# Call dictionary in tableView of swift

Tags: swift

How to call Dictionary values in tableView..

Getting error

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var tblView: UITableView!
    var AnimalName = ["e":["Elephant","EEE"","l":["Lion","LL"],h":["Horse",huh"]]
    var initial = Array(AnimalName.alKeys)   //error in this line

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return AnimalName.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = AnimalName[indexPath.row]  //how to call the cell

        return cell

    }

    func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return initial                         // not getting output
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
        return index                           // How to select 
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, it seems as if your dictionary is not properly defined. Take an extra look at how you're defining your dictionary `AnimalName`. Try `var AnimalName : [String:[String]] = ["e":["Elephant","EEE"],"l":["Lion","LL"],"h":["Horse","huh"]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

   @IBOutlet var tblView: UITableView!
   var AnimalName = ["e":["Elephant","EEE"], "l":["Lion","LL"], "h":["Horse", "huh"]]
   var initial: [String] = []   //error in this line

   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return self.initial.count
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if let animalsOfSection = self.AnimalName[self.initial[section]] {
         return animalsOfSection.count
      }
      return 0
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

      if let animal = self.AnimalName[self.initial[indexPath.section]]?[indexPath.row] {
         cell.textLabel?.text = animal  //how to call the cell
      }


      return cell

   }

   func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
      return self.initial                         // not getting output
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
      if let index = self.initial.indexOf(title) {
         return index                           // How to select
      }
      return 0
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
      self.initial = Array(self.AnimalName.keys).sort(<)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

["Horse",huh"] should be ["Horse","huh"]

"EEE""  should be "EEE"]

"LL"],h"  should be "LL"],"h"

var initial = Array(AnimalName.alKeys)
should be
var initial = Array(AnimalName.keys)

You shouldn't need SO to find and fix typos.  Also, try Ctrl+Space after a period, it will propose the appropriate function names and help you avoid misnaming them.